# Type for pairs (x,y) with (x/=y)

Tags: syntax, dependent-type, idris

I'd like to set up a type for pairs `(x, y)` with `x /= y`.

My idea is to define `NEqPa : Type -> Type` such that `NEqPa a` should contain all the elements `((x,y), p)` with `x : a`, `y : a` and `p : (x = y) -> Void`.  I tried the following two versions:

```
NEqPa a = ((x, y) : (a, a) ** (x = y) -> Void)

NEqPa a = ((x : a, y : a) ** (x = y) -> Void)
```

Both seem to be syntactically incorrect but I have no idea how to fix them.

[EDIT] I found a solution:

```
NEqPa a = (p : (a, a) ** (fst p = snd p) -> Void)
```

Is this approach reasonable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax sugar of `**` is a bit unwieldy to use when you want to add explicit type annotation on the first coordinate. I'd just use `DPair` directly:

```
NEqPa : Type -> Type
NEqPa a = DPair (a, a) $ \(x, y) => Not (x = y)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any source which you can recommend if I want to learn in detail about Idris' Syntax?  There is no language report yet, is it?